# Filling Value of a Pandas Data Frame From a Large DB Query (Python)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, optimization, dataframe

I am running a snippet of code that queries a database and then fills in a pandas dataframe with a value of 1 if that tuple is present in the query. it does this by running the query then iterates over the tuples and fills in the dataframe. However, the query returns almost 8 million rows of data.

My question is if anyone knows how to speed up a process like this. Here is the code below:

```
user_age = pd.read_sql_query(sql_age, datastore, index_col=['userid']).age.astype(np.int, copy=False)
x = pd.DataFrame(0, index=user_age.index, columns=range(366), dtype=np.int8)

for r in pd.read_sql_query(sql_active, datastore, chunksize=50000):
        for userid, day in r.itertuples(index=False):
            x.at[userid, day] = 1
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is brutal.  I can't think of a quicker way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save some time by replacing the Python loop

```
for userid, day in r.itertuples(index=False):
    x.at[userid, day] = 1
```

with a NumPy array assignment using "advanced integer indexing":

```
x[npidx[r['userid']], r['day']] = 1
```

---

On a 80000-row DataFrame, `using_numpy` (below) is about 6x faster:

```
In [7]: %timeit orig()
1 loop, best of 3: 984 ms per loop

In [8]: %timeit using_numpy()
10 loops, best of 3: 162 ms per loop
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def mock_read_sql_query():
    np.random.seed(2016)
    for arr in np.array_split(index, N//M):
        size = len(arr)
        df = pd.DataFrame({'userid':arr , 'day':np.random.randint(366, size=size)})
        df = df[['userid', 'day']]
        yield df

N, M = 8*10**4, 5*10**2
index = np.arange(N)
np.random.shuffle(index)
columns = range(366)

def using_numpy():
    npidx = np.empty_like(index)
    npidx[index] = np.arange(len(index))
    x = np.zeros((len(index), len(columns)), dtype=np.int8)
    for r in mock_read_sql_query():
        x[npidx[r['userid']], r['day']] = 1
    x = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=columns, index=index)
    return x

def orig():
    x = pd.DataFrame(0, index=index, columns=columns, dtype=np.int8)
    for r in mock_read_sql_query():
        for userid, day in r.itertuples(index=False):
            x.at[userid, day] = 1
    return x

expected = orig()
result = using_numpy()

expected_index, expected_col = np.where(expected)
result_index, result_col = np.where(result)
assert np.equal(expected_index, result_index).all()
assert np.equal(expected_col, result_col).all()
```